# How to make the transition from positions to animate in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I have a menubar which when clicked toggles the display of menu items. After the menu bar there are set of paragraphs. I want to make the hide and show the menu item smooth with the paragraphs container changing position with a transition. Currently I am only able to add transition effect to the menu item toggle but the paragraph changing the position is still not getting animated. How to animate this?

Please find the sample at https://jsfiddle.net/kadaj/f8sua52p/

```
<div id="menubar">
  <div class="menu-item" data-id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="menu-item tags" data-id="tag">Tags</div>
  <div class="menu-item" data-id="archive">Archive</div>
  <div class="menu-item" data-id="example">Example</div>
  <div class="menu-item" data-id="download">Download</div>
  <div class="menu-item" data-id="about">About</div>
</div>
<div id='tags-wrapper' class='menu-item-wrapper hide-menu-item'>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Bannana</li>
    <li>Cherry</li>
    <li>Blueberry</li>
    <li>Blackberry</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

```
document.querySelector("#menubar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  switch (e.target.dataset.id) {
    case "tag":
      let elem = document.querySelector("#tags-wrapper");
      if (elem.classList.contains("show-menu-item")) {  // hide
        elem.classList.add("hide-menu-item");
        elem.classList.remove("show-menu-item");
      } else {  // show
        elem.classList.add("show-menu-item");
        elem.classList.remove("hide-menu-item");
      }
      break;
  }
}, false);
```

```
#menubar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 1em;
}
.menu-item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.menu-item-wrapper {
  transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.17, 1.1, 1, 1);
}
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
.display-block {
  display: block
}
.show-menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hide-menu-item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: smooth 1s 0.3s ease-out forwards;  /* I tried different ways, but these are not working */
}
@keyframes smooth {   /* not working */
  to {
    background: coral;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: You'd likely get more feedback if you switched from jsfiddle and moved your code to a snippet in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max-height` trick. Also, you don't need that animation.
Edit the properties for these classes:

```
.hide-menu-item {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: 0.36s;
}
.show-menu-item {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
}
.menu-item-wrapper {
    transition: 2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 1.1, 1, 1);
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The issue is not with the display of tags, but the transition when the tags gets shown and hidden. The transition of the paragraph hight.

Comment: Edited. Is that what you meant? I hope I got it right now.

Comment: Yes, wonderful. Thank you :). I had spent a while to get this working.